# S3Download task in Azure Devops failing with "ENOENT: no such file or directory" after task successfully queues correct download items

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have configured (I believe) a service connection to AWS from Azure Devops in service connections from which i'm pulling some image assets to be used in the iOS build.
The credentials seem to be OK as it's listing the correct files from the bucket (and it's nestled sub folders), it is hitting an error when it goes to save on the build agent.

Here is the security scrubbed S3 download task in the pipeline:

```
- task: S3Download@1
  inputs:
    awsCredientials: 'AWSCREDS'
    regionName: 'us-somewhere-1'
    bucketName: 'bucketname'
    globExpressions: 'NameOfFolderToSearchOnS3/**'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

in S3Download logs of pipeline in Azure Devops:

```
...
112 Queueing download NameOfFolderToSearchOnS3/Splash Screens/ios/iphone-portrait-ios-8,8@retina.png
113 Queueing download NameOfFolderToSearchOnS3/Splash Screens/ios/iphone-portrait-ios-5,6@2x.png
##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/runner/work/1/a/NameOfFolderToSearchOnS3/
Finishing: S3Download
```

It seems like it's not writing because that folder doesn't exist.  Do need to implicitly create the folder and sub folders prior to the download? is there a way for it to create the directory scaffolding as part of the download task?

-Thanks!

I have tried changing the target folder to no avail.
I tried to put a quick bash script to just 'mkdir NameOfFolderToSearchOnS3' prior to s3download but still throwing same error on a nestled sub folder
I am assuming that since it's locating the correct files in the s3 bucket that its queuing that the service connection is setup up properly between AWS-Azure Devops

Comment: In testing, I added a 'flattenFolders: true' to the s3download@1 task and it's now downloading the files into the projects base directory.  This seems to be a hackneyed work around, as its obliterating the folder structure and organization of the s3download into an untenable mess.  Any ideas how to preserve?

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue [S3Download fails unless flattenFolders is used](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/468).

> It is not correctly creating all the intermediate folders for download.

So, it seems a known bug and pending release.